# Searching through an object Array and Deleting a specific object

Tags: java, arrays

I'm currently working on a shopping cart program, the program works by adding objects to an `ArrayList` that then gets printed on a `JTextArea` . The program needs to have the functionality of removing items as well. The user will input a unique order number of the order they would like to remove, I know how to get the number they have inputted, but I don't know how I can then use that number to run through my `Array` and delete the correct object.

Comment: Iterate through the list, compare that number and remove the matching one.

Comment: ArrayList.remove() method doesn't work ?

Comment: how can I compare the number they entered with attributes of objects in the array list?

Comment: @radimpe That is not a duplicate. The question is not a duplicate (which is the core criteria), but even the selected answer isn't really relevant.

Comment: The closure went ahead anyway. I've voted to re-open - the suggested duplicate is not valid.

Answer (score 3):

Use an [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) to loop around your objects. Compare the relevant field in the object with the value from the user. If you get a match, remove the object and stop searching.

```
Iterator<OrderObject> iterator = yourList.iterator();
boolean found = false;

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  OrderObject o = iterator.next();
  if (o.getSomeField() == numberFromUser) {
    iterator.remove();
    found = true;
    break;
  }
}

if (!found) {
   // opportunity here to alert user?
}
```

Comment: Iterator<OrderObject> iterator = yourList.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  OrderObject o = iterator.next();
  if (o.someField == numberFromUser) {
    iterator.remove();
    break;
  }
}

Comment: I think he gave you the same code which you put in the comment. What you want to imply by that?